# Is it possible to export typescript interface as output from a method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, interface, jsonschema

I have a method that converts JSON schema to Typescript interface "string". 
It looks like this:

//Input

```
var scriptSchema = {
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
       src: { type: 'string' },
       name: { type: 'string' },
       author: { type: 'string' }
    },
    required: ['src','name']
}
```

//Output (As a string)

```
interface IScript {
   src: string,
   name: string,
   author?: string
}
```

I'd like to avoid generating a file to house this if possible.

Ideally if possible I'd like to do something like this.

```
export interface IScript = JSON.parse(...) //etc, etc
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - at least not without emitting valid new TypeScript code and compiling it as a post-step.

This restriction is because TypeScript is a [Statically Typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_and_dynamic_type_checking_in_practice) language and it must have all the type information during type-validation and [trans]compilation. No *value* from the future execution of a program is available at this.

It seems like the end-goal is to 'dynamically generate' various TypeScript types. In this case using separate files (and a separate generation phase) is probably the most .. useful.

Comment: Yeah this was my conclusion as well. I'll give this question another hour, if no miracles discovered I'll accept this answer.